# How to sum multiple field with specific condition for each field

Tags: mysql

I want to put condition to the SUM. For example SUM rates.negative will have condition where is_active = 0

This is the link DB Fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cd6fe488fcefcd000274a3c67590dede

This is the sample query without the condition

```
SELECT 
    comments.*, 
    SUM(
        rates.score
    ), 
    SUM(
        rates.negative
    )  
FROM comments 
    WHERE rates.comment_id = comments.id
GROUP BY comments.id
```

Output

[image]

If I put the condition using WHEN, I get this error.

```
SELECT 
    comments.*, 
    SUM(
        rates.score
    ), 
    SUM(
        rates.negative WHEN rates.is_active = '0'
    )  
FROM comments 
    WHERE rates.comment_id = comments.id
GROUP BY comments.id
```

Error

```
Error syntax near WHEN rates.is_active = '0'
```

How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax is to use [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression, for conditional aggregation. Moreover, for multi-table queries, it if preferable to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) for code clarity and readability.

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    SUM(
        r.score
    ) AS score_sum, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN r.is_active = '0' THEN r.negative ELSE 0 END
    ) AS negative_sum
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN rates AS r ON (r.comment_id = c.id)
WHERE r.comment_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

DB fiddle Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6b344f7653249c53a38e64a9f81bee19

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CS.id AS comment_id,
    SUM(RS.score) AS score_sum,
    SUM(CASE RS.is_active WHEN 0 THEN RS.negative ELSE 0 END) AS negative_sum
FROM comments AS CS 
LEFT JOIN rates AS RS ON (RS.comment_id = CS.id)
GROUP BY CS.id
```

DB File Demo 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=696a1648f0d2a9baa8330ed9b686fd81

Hope This Will Help You